# DataGrip reports "Unknown system variable 'query_cache_type' when connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip, query-cache

When using DataGrip to connect to MySQL, there is a connection error. I know it can be solved by modify MySQL server configuration, but is there a client way?

> [HY000][1193] Unknown system variable 'query_cache_type'

Comment: Can you please tell us the version of the driver you use?

Comment: @moscas  "Use provided driver MYSQL Connector/J[latest]"

Comment: Please, clarify your MySQL version and DataGrip version (we hope it is 2017.1.1)

Comment: Got the same issue with Datagrip 2.2 and Mysql version 8 (pretty sure mysql version is the issue here).

Answer (score 3):

Are you using MySQL 8.0.3? The new version has [removed support for the query cache (for good reason)](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/), and the variables that pertain to it.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html says:

> **Note**
>
> The query cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0.

I just installed the latest DataGrip 2017.2.2 and the latest MySQL 8.0.3-RC and I can reproduce the error you report. I was able to use DataGrip fine with MySQL 8.0.1.

I have logged a bug with DataGrip: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5212

---

Update: the JetBrains bug report referred me to this MySQL JDBC driver bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87846

TL;DR:

> You need to use Connector/J 5.1.44 to connect to MySQL 8.0.3.

I followed these steps:

1. Download the free MySQL Connector/J 5.1.44 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/
2. Open DataGrip's Data Sources inspector with `Cmd-;`
3. Select the MySQL driver
4. Uncheck the use of the bundles MySQL Connector/J
5. Click "+" to add a file, and select the MySQL Connector/J jar that I had downloaded
6. Restart DataGrip

Once I had done that, queries in DataGrip work against MySQL 8.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the driver to MariaDB and that works for me.

Changing to the last version of MySQL didn't help.